# Systemd timer is irregular

Tags: scheduled-tasks, cron, systemd

I am trying to set up a systemd timer that will run every 5 seconds (it will be sending realtime stats to a remote server) as explained [here](http://blog.dcycle.com/blog/112/systemd-replacement-cron-every-10-seconds/).

Service

```
[Unit]
Description=PHP Cron
Wants=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
StandardOutput=null
StandardError=syslog
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/date >> /tmp/date"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Timer

```
[Unit]
Description=Run cron service every 5 seconds

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*:*:0/5
```

Unfortunately, the timer is very irregular.

```
Fri Dec 29 12:21:21 IST 2017
Fri Dec 29 12:21:25 IST 2017
Fri Dec 29 12:21:33 IST 2017
Fri Dec 29 12:21:36 IST 2017
Fri Dec 29 12:21:41 IST 2017
Fri Dec 29 12:21:48 IST 2017
Fri Dec 29 12:21:52 IST 2017
Fri Dec 29 12:22:01 IST 2017
Fri Dec 29 12:22:07 IST 2017
Fri Dec 29 12:22:13 IST 2017
Fri Dec 29 12:22:23 IST 2017
```

Why is this so? Is systemd timers unreliable when used with interval lower than a minute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, systemd uses a very low accuracy so that jobs of multiple timers (i.e. different tasks all happening within a few seconds) could be grouped into a single run, after which the system can continue idling.

The option can be set in `[Timer]` and you'll want to set it to `1s` or lower.

```
    AccuracySec=
       Specify the accuracy the timer shall elapse with. Defaults to 1min. The timer is
       scheduled to elapse within a time window starting with the time specified in
       OnCalendar=, OnActiveSec=, OnBootSec=, OnStartupSec=, OnUnitActiveSec= or
       OnUnitInactiveSec= and ending the time configured with AccuracySec= later. Within
       this time window, the expiry time will be placed at a host-specific, randomized,
       but stable position that is synchronized between all local timer units. This is
       done in order to optimize power consumption to suppress unnecessary CPU wake-ups.
       To get best accuracy, set this option to 1us. Note that the timer is still
       subject to the timer slack configured via systemd-system.conf(5)'s
       TimerSlackNSec= setting. See prctl(2) for details. To optimize power consumption,
       make sure to set this value as high as possible and as low as necessary.
```

Comment: Thank you. It is now working perfectly. `This is done in order to optimize power consumption to suppress unnecessary CPU wake-ups.` Will it have any power saving effect on a busy multi core server, since the CPU is never idle?